# Replace multiple elements in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am learning the intermediate python.

Suppose there's a string

```
astring = '[Embodied cognition - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition)'
```

Work with `string.punctuation` to extract the words

```
from string import punctuation
for delimiter in punctuation:
    if delimiter in astring:
        astring = astring.replace(delimiter, ' ')

In [7]: astring
Out[7]: ' Embodied cognition   Wikipedia  https   en wikipedia org wiki Embodied cognition '
```

I tried with `map` and it works

```
In [12]: a = map(astring.replace, punctuation, ' ')
In [14]: list(a)
Out[14]: [' Embodied cognition   Wikipedia  https   en wikipedia org wiki Embodied cognition ']
```

How can the problem be solved in other advanced techniques?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `map` should be padding your string `' '` argument with `None`, if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Comment: sorry, I  complement `python3.6` tag immediately. @SilvioMayolo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into regular expressions (regex for short).

```
import re

astring = '[Embodied cognition - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition)'
re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', astring)
# returns:
' Embodied cognition Wikipedia https en wikipedia org wiki Embodied cognition '
```

Comment: Thank you. I learned regex last Saturday. It dramatically improve efficiency to process text.